# Check whether a total column amount match a value from another table

Tags: sql, syntax

I have two tables as described below:

Table A:

| Outlet | Customer_No | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 15000 |
| A | 2 | 12500 |
| B | 3 | 18000 |

Table B:

| Outlet | Customer_No | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 19000 |
| A | 2 | 19000 |
| B | 3 | 5000 |
| C | 1 | 17000 |

I need to write logic to check if the total amount of an outlet in table A match the total amount of that outlet in table B. If it does then prints out 'Match', or if it doesn't match then prints out 'Not Match'. I have tried using a case expression but I might have written the syntax wrong.

```
select 
    case 
        when sum(a.Amount) = sum(b.Amount) where a.Outlet = b.Outlet
            then print 'Match'
            else 
                when sum(a.Amount) != sum(b.Amount) where a.Outlet = b.Outlet
                    then print 'Not Match'
    end
from
    Table A a, Table B b
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result. (I.e. make a complete [mcve].)

Comment: The syntax is `case when ... then ... [ else  ... ] end`.

Comment: The expected result would be in a form of text output printed either 'Match' or 'Not Match'

Comment: That's _describing_, not _specifying_. One row, several rows? Which columns?

Comment: Just one row, on a new column I guess.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `INNER JOIN` to match only the records that are on both tables, and `CASE` clause to check if matched or not :

```
select a.Outlet, sum(a.Amount) as total_Outlet_a, total_Outlet_b,
       case when sum(a.Amount) = total_Outlet_b then 'MATCH' else 'NOT MATCH' END AS 'IS MATCHED'
from tableA a
inner join (
  select Outlet, sum(Amount) as total_Outlet_b
  from tableB
  group by Outlet
) as b on a.Outlet = b.Outlet
group by Outlet
```

Results :

```
Outlet  total_Outlet_a  total_Outlet_b  IS MATCHED
A       27500           38000           NOT MATCH
B       18000           5000            NOT MATCH
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tn0G19Zf)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is making a union of all your records, while keeping positive amounts for table a, and negating the amounts of table b. In this way, when you carry out the sum, the two tables will have the same amount if the aggregation over the Outlet gives 0 as output.

```
SELECT Outlet,
       CASE WHEN SUM(Amount) = 0 
            THEN 'Match' 
            ELSE 'Not Match' 
       END AS outcome
FROM (SELECT Outlet, Amount FROM tabA
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Outlet, -Amount FROM tabB) cte
GROUP BY Outlet
```

**Output**:

| Outlet | outcome |
| --- | --- |
| A | Not Match |
| B | Not Match |
| C | Not Match |

Here's a [demo in MySQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pQDvQp6Rd1zCYoqL3MqchC/1), although this code should work in all the most common DBMSs.